# Python, ctypes, and parallelization

Tags: python, multithreading, ctypes

If I call a multithreaded shared-library and give it a set of Python callbacks, it's correct to assume that the GIL will still be a problem while the Python is executing, correct?

Dustin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unclear what you mean by "a problem".  The library must acquire the GIL before calling back into Python, and because of the GIL only one thread at a time can execute Python-level code.  But there's nothing that requires the library to wait for the callback to return - it *can* continue doing as much as it likes in its own threads.  Whether that's semantically *correct* depends on knowing exact details of what the library is doing.

Comment: "The library must acquire the GIL before calling back into Python".. That's exactly what I was asking. I always refer to GIL as a problem in the context of multithreading, as, I'm sure, most people do.